# mysql unique field .. postprocess with php

Tags: php, mysql

Hy,

I have a `users` table in mysql with `username` and `alias` set to `UNIQUE` .If i try to insert something that already is there i get the error : `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Ramocea' for key 'alias'` which is good.

But i want to show the users messages like this :

`Alias already exist in database` and `Username already exist in the database` not that mysql_error .

Is there need for a check to the database and `if $mysqi->num_rows > 0 - return false;` ? Or is there a method to manipulate what mysql throws as error and replace the messages ?

Thank you very much ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do everything in one query:

```
if (!mysql_query("INSERT INTO table ...")) {
    switch (mysql_errno()) {
        case 1062:
           echo ""; // parse mysql_error() here for a key
           break;
        //case ...
    }
}
```

But I would recommend you to check for existing values beforehand:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE unique_field = ...");
if (mysql_num_rows($res)) {
    echo "Something already exist in database";
}
```

Comment: That is 1. st method in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Method: Before doing INSERT, do SELECT with same data. Then you will know, if there already exists a data, and warn user.
2. Catch (read the error), check if it contains string "Duplicate entry", and if so, then warn the user.

Comment: Thanks ... but how to catch it ? I think is that try / catch but i don't understand how